# Reapplying for Schengen Visa of same country

Tags: schengen, schengen-visas

I got my Schengen visa from german consulate and travelled to Germany earlier this year but from the time of issuing visa to travelling, my travel route changed.

Itinerary i submitted was: Delhi to Frankfurt and then Frankfurt to Delhi.

But later on when i travelled, i was to visit London for official trip. So i travelled via Eurostar from London to Brussels and then to Cologne. 
And While returning i had a connecting flight from Frankfurt to Amsterdam to Delhi.
All my stay was in Germany only but because of new travel route, my passport got stamped in London while boarding Eurostar and then in Amsterdam as flight from Amsterdam to Frankfurt didn't involved passing through Immigration.

Now i will be visiting Germany again and will be reapplying for Visa but i am wondering as there are no German stamps in my passport, will it cause any issue?

Comment: Since one must apply for a visa for the country of longest stay and not the country of entry/departure not having entry/exit stamps from the visa issuing country would not be a problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's possible, but unlikely.  The fact that your passport was stamped in the Netherlands rather than in Germany is not particularly important.

You can include a statement with your application explaining how your plans changed, and any evidence of your time in Germany showing that the purpose of your trip was unchanged even if your travel to Germany was by a different route.  Such evidence could be a copy of your boarding passes or of hotel or other receipts from your stay in Germany.

Comment: I can attach evidence but should i do it proactively or wait for them to ask for it?

Comment: @Lokesh I suppose it's better to do it proactively.  If you don't, it's more likely that they will refuse the application, and you'll have to pay another application fee to submit the evidence with your new application.